# Spring MVC WebSocket: Unexpected response code: 302

Tags: spring-mvc, websocket

My Spring webapp is deployed at http://localhost:8080/mycontext.
I am trying to set up simple websocket communication based on the example at https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring

I set up a`WebSocketConfig` class as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler(new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy())).withSockJS();
    }
}
```

and my client page, in javascript, does the following:

```
function connect() {
    require([ 'SockJSlib' ], function(SockJS) {
        var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/mycontext/chat');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);  
        stompClient.debug = function(str) {
            console.debug(str + "\n");
        }
        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
            //do things I need to do when connected
        });
    });
}
```

Problem is, when the connection is attempted, my Chrome console is showing the following:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/mycontext/chat/499/3ddwpqq2/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302

POST http://localhost:8080/mycontext/chat/096/s1figjsq/xhr_streaming?t=1536238976679 403 (Forbidden)

EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.

POST http://localhost:8080/mycontext/chat/096/onuq0m1f/xhr?t=1536238977361 403 (Forbidden)
```

I have been reading various posts here on SO and elsewhere. Some of them suggest setting the `DefaultHandshakeHandler` (which I did to no change). Others suggest using `setAllowedOrigins("*")` when defining the endpoint, but I cannot do that as I am stuck on Spring 4.1.0 and that version of spring websocket does not implement that method.

If I connect in the browser to `http://localhost:8080/mycontext/chat` I get "Welcome to SockJS", so the server part looks like it's working.

I'm a bit confused if the real problem is hiding behind the 302 error, or behind the 403. I have authorized for the moment the `/chat/**` URLs to have no security:

```
<http pattern="/chat/**" security="none" />
```

But this does not make the errors go away.

I am a bit of a loss of solutions here. Any idea of what am I missing/doing wrong?

Thanks.